# How do I create a custom config file in xboxdrv?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, usb, xbox-360

I just got a wireless xbox 360 controller with a usb receiver.  I have tried to use `xboxdrv` to get it working as a mouse.  The `--mouse` command works alright, but I wanted to customize some of the buttons.
I have looked [here](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/xboxdrv.html), but I'm not particularly sure of my way around terminal, so I wouldn't mind a bit of help.
I understand you have to use `--ui-buttonmap BTN=SYM` but I don't see how to put them all together in a file.  Could someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory where the example files are located is:

```
/usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/examples/mouse.xboxdrv
```

I used the original mouse file as an example.  Then I created a `.xboxdrv` file in a different directory and can open it with `--config`
Simple once I figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

See the [mouse.xboxdrv](https://github.com/Grumbel/xboxdrv/blob/stable/examples/mouse.xboxdrv) example file, which you can load via:

```
xboxdrv --config example/mouse.xboxdrv
```

Simply modify that to your liking.

Comment: ok, I figured it out in the end!  I saw one of your posts on another forum.  I'm really enjoying it, now I've got it to work!